# golang build by copying vendor folder

Tags: docker, go

My Project structure

```
/github.com/user
 - libraries
 - services
     - service-api-signup
          - Dockerfile
          - main.go
     - service-api-second
          - ...
 - vendor
```

Docker file inside service-api-signup

```
FROM golang
COPY . /go/src/github.com/user/services/service-api-signup

# need to copy all the dependencies on vendor to /go/src/github.com/..
```

How can copy all my dependencies on vendor and libraries folder to go path on docker image to build ?
(need to copy from parent directory and build)

Any way to setup my development environment ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way is to use a dependency manager such as [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep).

An alternative is just to copy the vendor directory directly in your Dockerfile, but this is not ideal, as it will copy the entire vendor directory verbatim, even if it contains old or unused imports.

Comment: if I use dep inside docker file it tries to get my libraries files and vendor packages into docker image ? or it tries to install from github.com ?

Comment: Why are you building your code inside Docker in the first place? Why not build, then just copy the executable, and any other needed artifacts, into the Docker image?

Comment: But to answer your question, it would install from the network typically (whether github or not, I have no idea, since I don't know what you're importing)

Comment: this is for my development setup. I need to run 10 services on my machine and should be able to edit codes. I can copy and just run main.go.

Comment: How can I copy "An alternative is just to copy the vendor directory directly in your Dockerfile" because these are outside the directory of docker file. I tried with ADD ... but no file or directory found error.  Any way to copy ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a kind of monorepo setup, with vendor at the top level and then dockerfiles in each of the sub directories (/services) you could use a top level `docker-compose.yml` file ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)) to define all the services and then use volume mounts to ensure that vendor ends up inside the containers.

Taking your example

```
.../repo
 - libraries
 - services
     - service-api-signup
          - Dockerfile
          - main.go
     - service-api-second
          - ...
 - vendor
 - docker-compose.yml
```

The `docker-compose.yml` would look something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-api-signup:
    container_name: api-signup
    build:
      context: ./service-api-signup
    volumes:
      - ./vendor:/go/src/github.com/user/services/service-api-signup/vendor
  service-api-second:
    container_name: api-second
    build:
      context: ./service-api-second
    volumes:
      - ./vendor:/go/src/github.com/user/services/service-api-second/vendor
```

There's also an option to override the command and entrypoint of a dockerfile allowing you to set custom scripts as the entrypoint when running through docker-compose

```
entrypoint: /go/src/github.com/user/services/service-api-signup
```

Maybe that script (that you would need to create and put in your repo somewhere) could make use of a live reload tool like [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) and might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

go get github.com/codegangsta/gin

exec gin --immediate -appPort 8080 run
```

This would still mean that you are building the application inside docker (which in OS's that aren't linux will mean worse performance). But it does mean that you get docker-compose convenience, live reload and don't need to rebuild containers.